# How do I Correctly Render Python Data in Jinja HTML Templates?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm extremely new to python/flask, so I don't have the capacity to describe what I'm doing wrong. Please be patient with me.

As I'm in the learning stages, my goal is to create a simple app with GET, PUT, POST, DELETE functionalities. I'm using flask to render a template for a project; I'm using forms to make an HTML page. The one key issue here is:

*in my routes.py*

```py
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    all_pokemon = Pokémon.query.all()

    result = ""
    for pokemon in all_pokemon:
        result += f"{pokemon.id} | {pokemon.pkname} | {pokemon.nickname}<br>" 
          
    return result
```

This, gives me what I want, which is this:

[image: correct]

However, I have an home.html setup to do exactly the same thing. Simply show me this information.

*in my home.html*

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} 

{% block body %}
<h1>version 1.0.0</h1>
<br>
    {% for pokemon in all_pokemon %} 
        {{ "{pokemon.id} | {pokemon.pkname} | {pokemon.nickname}" }}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock body %}
```

*and to get that working, i have this in my routes.py*

```py
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    all_pokemon = Pokémon.query.all()
    return render_template("home.html", all_pokemon=all_pokemon)
```

But, doing this, gives me this output:

[image: incorrect]

My question is, how do I get the render_template to NOT display the incorrect output, and to properly display the correct output of my forms?

I've been searching for an answer for this issue without an understanding of the proper terminology and have consequently made no progress for the past 3.5 hours. Any help is greatly appreciated. Swift help is incredibly appreciated.

Thank you. If I need to post more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, and as I suspected it was embarassingly simple.

The render template worked, but where I had

*in my home.html*

`{{ "{pokemon.id} | {pokemon.pkname} | {pokemon.nickname}" }}`

I should have had

`{{ pokemon.id }} | {{ pokemon.pkname }} | {{ pokemon.nickname }}`

I apologise for anybody who may have wasted their time searching for an answer, and I hope this can serve as a helpful guide to any other newbies like myself who get stuck on this.

Hopefully 7 years from now I can look back on this moment affectionately and laugh about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for pokemon in all_pokemon %} 
    {{ "{pokemon.id} | {pokemon.pkname} | {pokemon.nickname}" }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Firstly you should use your context like that:

```
{{pokemon.id}} | {{pokemon.pkname}} | {{pokemon.nickname}}
```

And if you want to render your context, your view should be like that:

```
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    all_pokemon = Pokémon.query.all()
    result = ""
    for pokemon in all_pokemon:
       result += f"{pokemon.id} | {pokemon.pkname} | {pokemon.nickname}<br>" 

    if all_pokemon is not None:
       return render_template("home.html", all_pokemon=all_pokemon, result=result)
    else:
        return render_template("home.html",all_pokemon=all_pokemon, result = "")
```

If you use your context named result, you should use a control in your template folder like that:

.html

```
 {% if result|length > 1 %}
  ...
 {% endif %}
```